# Search for exact match in string based on values in array

Tags: arrays, swift, string, swift3

I am trying to search for items in an array using a free text string.  I have got so far, see code below, but I'm still returning results which only partially match.

```
var townArray = ["Leamington Spa", "Birmingham", "Coventry", "Leamington Hastings", "Royal Leamington Spa", "Lea", "Leam", "Cove"]

let searchText = "Anyone want to meet in Leamington Spa or Coventry"

var resultsArray = [String]()

for i in townArray {
    let range = searchText.lowercased().range(of: i.lowercased(), options: .regularExpression)
    // (8 times)
    if range != nil {
    let found = searchText.substring(with: range!)
    print(found)
    resultsArray.append(found)
    // (5 times)}
}
print(resultsArray)
// ["Leamington Spa", "Coventry", "Lea", "Leam", "Cove"]
```

Comment: What do you expect? Your town array contains that partial strings. In this particular case the regular expression option is redundant.

Comment: I am expecting to return only "Leamington Spa" and "Coventry" as these are the cities specified in the searchText NOT "Leam", "Lea" or "Cove".

Answer (score 1):

Exact word matching is not a simple thing, you may need to use regular expression.

For example:

```
var townArray = ["Leamington Spa", "Birmingham", "Coventry", "Leamington Hastings", "Royal Leamington Spa", "Lea", "Leam", "Cove"]

let searchText = "Anyone want to meet in Leamington Spa or Coventry"

let townRegexArray = townArray.map {townName -> (name: String, regex: NSRegularExpression) in
    let pattern = townName.components(separatedBy: " ")
        .map{"\\b"+NSRegularExpression.escapedPattern(for: $0)+"\\b"}
        .joined(separator: "\\s+")
    //print(pattern) //->\bLeamington\b\s+\bSpa\b (=="\\bLeamington\\b\\s+\\bSpa\\b")...
    let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: .caseInsensitive)
    return (name: townName, regex: regex)
}
let resultsArray = townRegexArray
    .filter{$0.regex.firstMatch(in: searchText, range: NSRange(0..<searchText.utf16.count)) != nil}
    .map{$0.name}
print(resultsArray) //->["Leamington Spa", "Coventry"]
```

`\b` (`"\\b"` in String literal) represents word boundary in regex. So `\bLeam\b` does not match to `Leamington`.

Answer (score 0):

You would do something like this

```
let matchingStrings = resultsArray.filter { $0 == "TARGET_STRING" }
let containsString = !matchingStrings.isEmpty
```